# Replace "label.form.empty_value" of expanded entity type

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin

I want to render a relation/association field (i.e. `EntityType`) in EasyAdmin as radio buttons. My setup:

```
- property: 'group'
  type_options:
      expanded: true
```

What I'm getting is:

> o label.form.empty_value
>   o Admin
>   o User

How can I replace `label.form.empty_value` to something like "None"?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a [placeholder](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#placeholder) like this:

```
- property: 'group'
  type_options:
      expanded: true
      placeholder: 'None'
```